# How to split all objects within an array into 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let say I have an array:

```
array([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ...,
       ('x', 24), ('y', 25), ('z', 26)],
      dtype=object)
```

How do I split it into 2 columns as in 'alphabet' and 'order'? Much appreciated!

Comment: [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

Comment: A simple `pd.DataFrame(arr)` would also work.

Comment: Assuming the array `shape` is (n,2), then `arr[:,0]` will be a 1d array of the letters, and `arr[:,1}` the numbers.  You could also apply `astype` to change them to string and integer dtypes.  This is basic `numpy` coding.